# ntlm authentication in asp.net works in FF, not IE or Chrome

Tags: asp.net, ntlm

I just deployed some changes to my web app, restarted IIS, and suddenly I'm getting 401 errors all over the place.  EXCEPT if I enable NTLM authentication in Firefox:

1. browse to about:config, and agree not to mess anything up
2. filter by "trusted", then modify "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris" to include my app url, e.g. foo.mycompany.com
3. restart Firefox, and it gets into the app just fine

IE and Chrome will not let me in, even when I enter the DOMAIN\USERNAME and password.

Any ideas what would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a server reboot was needed.  Sheesh.  It appears that a patch/update was applied to the server that either required a reboot or should have, and in any case wasn't performed. My code rests vindicated, but the cries of my users still ring in my ears.